# Using let and yield in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `let` and `yield` in Firefox. I am testing in both versions 18 and 21 (Nightly) and getting the same results.

Here's my really simple test script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            'use strict';
            function a() {
                yield 5;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

[image: yield is a reserved identifier]

Similarly when I do a simple test with `let` I get "let is a reserved identifier", which is really frustrating because `let` [has supposedly existed in Firefox since version 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7)!

Strangely, if I execute the same code in Firebug it works!

I have tried various other strings in the `type` and `language` attributes of the `script` tag but have not found a magic one that works.

What's going on? How do I get this stuff working with a script tag?

---

### Edit

Hmm, I see, so you must specify the version number. I had tried this, but for my original more complicated script which used web workers. Apparently using `version=1.7` on a script which includes a web worker which includes a script that uses `let` and `yield` isn't good enough -- the web worker script still breaks... Then I tried reducing to simplest case but apparently didn't try `version=1.7` in simplest case.

Thanks... Might post another question in a little bit (after searching) on how to get this working for web workers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [mdn note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) said,

> The yield keyword is only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` block (or higher version)

So changing `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` will make it work.

Comment: Gotcha, I was sloppy in my testing. I really need it to work with web workers, as my edit says. I may post another question relating to that in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: This also fixed a similar issue for me I had with `let`. Strange that I have not seen that info somewhere in the docs before :-(

Comment: This appears to break IE 11