# Why the error message "SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier require.js:52:2" appears when developing firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am writing an firefox addon which uses Worker for background task. In **browserOverlay.js**:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("chrome://sample_xpcom/content/worker.js"); 
myWorker.postMessage({type: 10});
```

In **worker.js**:

```
importScripts("resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js")
//importScripts("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")

onmessage = function(e) {
 console.log('Message received from main script:' + e.data);
 if (e.data.type == 10) {
   console.log('data:' + e.data.type);
}
}
```

When first two lines is commented out it works perfectly. Otherwise I am getting an error **"SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier require.js:52:2"** in Browser console. According to MDN docs,   [OS.File for Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_workers) this way is correct. What am I doing wrong? Firefox version is 39.0.3.

Comment: Perhaps; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331617/using-let-and-yield-in-firefox

Comment: @limelights, how to specify `version=1.7` for script in Worker constructor? I have tried  `<script type="application/x-javascript;version=1.7 "src="..."/>` in **browserOverlay.xul** with no result

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue but was able to make my addon work by using ChromeWorker instead of normal worker.
try using

```
var myWorker = new ChromeWorker("chrome://sample_xpcom/content/worker.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

According to your comment:

> there is the line "use strict" and then "let require = (function(){...})

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> First, in strict mode a short list of identifiers become reserved keywords. These words are `implements, interface, let, package, private, protected, public, static, and yield`. In strict mode, then, you can't name or use variables or arguments with these names.

To answer your other question:

> Do I need to "clean" or reinstall firefox?

No, you need to use a different version of require.js.

## Original Answer

Most modern browsers allow you to use `let`, which provides for block-scoped variables.

For example:

```
let a = 5;
```

What is block scope? For example, in JavaScript if you declare a `var` inside an `if...else` block, the variable gets hoisted to the *top* of the scope. However, if you were to declare a `let` inside an `if...else`, it stays scopes to that `if...else` block.

`require.js` is likely using `let` as a key or somewhere else in the code, so the browser is yelling at you saying that `let` is a reserved keyword (which it is... it is a block-scoped variable declaration.)

It's akin to doing something like `var for = 5`. `for` is a reserved keyword, so you can't do it.

I just tried to do `var let = 5` in Firefox 39, and it gave an error as well.

Comment: Strange, the version of `require.js` has *no* naked `let` words, just those forming part of `complete` or `delete`. Not saying you're *wrong,* maybe OP has a different version.

Comment: @paxdiablo, can you elaborate "just those forming part of complete or delete"?

Comment: Josh, if I search my js file for `let`, it only shows lots of "de **let** e" and "comp **let** e" words.

Comment: How to fix this? I need modules/osfile.jsm for file I/O. I have read about "strong" syntax in JS. Looks like some JS libraries are incompatible. Do I need to "clean" or reinstall firefox?

Comment: @PavelMikhaylov, what do you mean by "strong" syntax? If you're referring to `'use strict';`, then yes, that disallows the use of any current ES6 features (like let, etc.) being used.

Comment: @josh-beam, I mean 'strict' syntax. In my require.js (in omni.ja) there is the line "use strict" and then  "let require = (function(){...})

Comment: @PavelMikhaylov, yeah that's the problem. Strict syntax doesn't allow the use of reserved identifiers. See the MDN docs: `First, in strict mode a short list of identifiers become reserved keywords. These words are implements, interface, let, package, private, protected, public, static, and yield. In strict mode, then, you can't name or use variables or arguments with these names.`.

Comment: @josh-beam, I can't use a different version of require.js. Initially I have added `importScripts("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")` at the top of the **worker.js** (according to MDN docs). That file includes "bad" require.js. Maybe should I import another 'require.js' **before** osfile.jsm? Which of them? In onmi.ja there are 5 different require.js

Comment: @PavelMikhaylov "I can't use a different version of require.js". Why not?

Comment: @josh-beam, because I need `resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm`. In `osfile.jsm` there is the line `importScripts("resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js",...)`. The last file leads to the error.

Comment: I know, question is 7 years old. but i stumbled over the same problem (fireFox "Let is a reserved .."). Starte same code in Chrome says: "Unexpected strict mode reserved word". 
That helped to fix the error. Perhaps someone is coming here and perhaps this can help.