# SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier 'let urlParts'. In angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firefox

I am a beginner in **angular2**, for practice purpose I have downloaded the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) code and tried to run it on my system locally, but every time I am running it an error is appearing.

> SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier
>
> let urlParts;

I came to know that `let` is the reserved keyword of `firefox`. But there must be a strong solution for that.

I have searched this issue on Google a lot, but could not get any satisfactory solution.
And I am running it by

> npm

I haven't made any changes in this code. Kindly guide.

Kindly ignore if I made any mistake in this question.

Comment: `let` is not reserved by Firefox, but by ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @DeepSpace you might be correct, but the error is clearly stating that it is a reserved identifier `SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier`

Comment: I never said it wasn't reserved. I only stated who it reserved by.

Comment: @DeepSpace So would you suggest me to use other version of ECMAScript, or an updated version of firefox, well for that i have already installed a new version of firefox ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198379/syntaxerror-let-is-a-reserved-identifier-on-firefox)