# How to fix "SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier" in VueJs application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I'm getting this error message in my VueJs application:

> SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier

This error pops up in old browsers (for example, FireFox 3x). I know, that it can be solved somehow using babel, but I'm new to it and need a solution.

My package.json now contains this property:

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
]
```

And my babel.config.js is as simple as:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@vue/app"]
}
```

What fixes should I add to make it work on old browsers?

Comment: did you try out `module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"
  ]
}` ?

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim, should I fix dependencies or devDependencies in package.json to make it work?

Comment: this is the content of `babel.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

Is likely because `let` is not supported in older browsers that doesn't support ES6. using `var` instead as a workaround by conditional check on browser's client type.

Link previous related thread: [SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198379/syntaxerror-let-is-a-reserved-identifier-on-firefox)

Comment: Well, this `let` keyword is used in a ton of packages imported to my application

Comment: I can not simply change all third-party libraries source code

Comment: Then can't be helped much. Whether to validate browser' support `let` or narrow down your scope of supported browsers if your application is very dependent. IE10-equivalent browsers will automatically get an update (such as New Edge) soon enough. You can't literally `let` one code to support whole list of browsers