# 'let' Keyword in Firefox 43.0.2 not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, let

I have read where the 'let' keyword is working now in Firefox, and that the use of specifying the version in the script tag is no longer necessary. HOWEVER, despite adding strict mode, I am still getting the Firefox error:

[image]

I'd tried block scoping strict mode, using the version in the script tag and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas on what may cause this persistent error for the 'let' keyword in Firefox? Or anything I may be able to eliminate as a cause? Thanx!!!

Comment: Use `var`  ... or go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331617/using-let-and-yield-in-firefox

Comment: in FF 44 check out [ES6 Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: Added in 44 - https://bugzil.la/932517

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let), `let` is not supported in FF 43. You still can use `var` for now as a [temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778275/1104483) workaround.