# Difference in interpretation between Firefox and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, ecmascript-6

I have come across an anomaly between Firefox and Node.js. Given the following code:

```
'use strict';
const obj = {};
for (let f of ['left', 'right']) {
  obj[f] = function() {
    return f;
  };
}
console.log(obj.left());
console.log(obj.right());
```

Firefox (48.0) outputs

```
right
right
```

while Node.js (6.4.0) outputs

```
left
right
```

Both on Ubuntu 14.04. I didn't have the possibility to test with other ECMAScript engines.

Any idea what is the reason for the difference, and which implementation is correct with respect to the specification?

Comment: Have you tried enabling strict mode?

Comment: @Bergi same output, I have edited the original question though to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not in the situation to check, but I would believe node behavior is the correct one here

Comment: Ah, so it's not ['let' Keyword in Firefox 43.0.2 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34684892/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi nope, I would have put 'const' if Firefox didn't currently break on such constructions. But that is besides the point. Even if I use a traditional loop, I get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Node is correct here, `let` in a `for` loop should have block scope.

FF 48 [simply doesn't support "*for/for-in loop iteration scope*"](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let_for/for-in_loop_iteration_scope) yet, it appears to be fixed with FF 51.

Comment: Additional verification that node/v8 is correct here is the relevant tc39/test262 test [here](https://github.com/tc39/test262/blob/44c65fd02ae71873499f1a4151ff01b7e23eb677/test/language/statements/for-of/let-fresh-binding-per-iteration-for-of.js).

Comment: @mscdex: I didn't think that "additional verification" such as a spec link was necessary, `let` scoping in ES6 is common knowledge by now :-)

Comment: I'm just pointing out that that repo is handy if in doubt about JavaScript behavior (in general), since it's maintained by the people who write the language specifications. Can't get more definitive than that.

Comment: @mscdex I would consider [the spec itself](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset) to be more definitive than any spec tests :-)

Comment: IMHO the tests are *easier* to read/understand for most people than the language in the spec.