# Mozilla Possible let vs var Bug

Tags: firefox, ecmascript-6, let, for-of-loop

Please consider the following JavaScript code:

```
let funcs = []
for(let x of [1,2,3]) {
    funcs[x] = function(){
        console.log("test:", x)
    }
}

funcs[1]()
funcs[2]()
funcs[3]()
```

When I run this code in Google Chrome V55.0 it generates the expected output of

```
test: 1
test: 2
test: 3
```

in the browser console. However, if I run the same code in Firefox V50.1.0, I get the following console output:

```
test: 3
test: 3
test: 3
```

The link [here](https://shadtechblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/how-does-es6-let-solve-closure-scope-problem/) (about a third of the way down at "Block Scope with Let") suggests that the Chrome console output is the correct one, but I would like to use the same code in both browsers. Can someone point out if I've made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: FF50 doesn't support iteration scope. FF51 will.

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: [Difference in interpretation between Firefox and Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39516179/1048572)