# Is it possible to run Angular 2.x-5.x in Firefox 17.0.4

Tags: angularjs, angular, firefox

We need to support Firefox 17.0.4 in production. We currently have an angular 1.6 application running in plain javascript. We are currently refactoring the application to include typescript. Is it possible to run angular 2.x-5.x in Firefox 17.0.4. I did a couple of POC with polyfills with or without webpack different versions of node etc. but I get some errors like:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object @ polyfills.bundle.js:1777
SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier @ vendor.bundle.js:485
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined @ node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:217
ReferenceError: System is not defined @ systemjs.config.js:1
```

**If someone has done it, what would be the exact setup/configuration/polyfills I would need?**

Comment: Did you take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support ?

Comment: Yes of course I did.

Comment: Okay, I found a post with the same problem you've got: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331617/using-let-and-yield-in-firefox/14331721 could you try it (if you didn't already) ? :)